# Duplicate zip entry : android/support/v4/media/VolumeProviderCompat$ControlType

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Can't write [/Users/admin/Documents/Tony Project/LOLC/Test/two news feed/HDMI/app/build/intermediates/multi-dex/debug/componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [/Users/admin/Documents/Tony Project/LOLC/Test/two news feed/HDMI/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/9.jar] (Duplicate zip entry [9.jar:android/support/v4/media/VolumeProviderCompat$ControlType.class]))
```

In the module.gradle I have added 
**multiDexEnabled true** then I got this error

Comment: can you share your gradle code?

Comment: maybe you can change two news feed folder to two_news_feed

Comment: Why did you enable Multidex? What are you compiling?

Answer (score -1):

You should try to clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: Yes.each time I got that one.

Comment: then invalidate caches and restart

Answer (score -1):

Add this in your local.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=512m -Xmx512m
```

Set `multiDexEnabled = true` in build.gradle

Comment: That's not the only step to enable Multidex